Using asterisk and spaces print the letter R [ 21*20]
I want to print the letter r as shown in image using asterisk and spaces

So far i was only able to do this shape

rows = 21  # Height of the letter R
cols = 20  # Width of the letter R

for i in range(rows + 2):  #     Adding 2 for top and bottom border
for j in range(cols + 2):  # Adding 2 for left and right border
    # Print a border of asterisks
    if i == 0 or i == rows + 1 or j == 0 or j == cols + 1:
        print("*", end=" ")
    # Print the letter "R"
    elif j == 1 and (i > 0 and i < rows + 1):  # Left vertical line
        print("*", end=" ")
    elif i == 1 and j < cols:  # Top horizontal line of R
        print("*", end=" ")
    elif i == rows // 2 and j < cols:  # Middle horizontal line of R
        print("*", end=" ")
    elif (i - j == 1) and (i > rows // 2):  # Diagonal line of R
        print("*", end=" ")
    else:
        print(" ", end=" ")  # Space inside the R
print()  # Move to the next line


using two ‘for loops’ and conditions

You say the matrix is 20x21 but the image seems to suggest otherwise - i.e., there are spaces in between the asterisks

Given that the letter always alternates a sequence of stars and spaces, you can encode the letter using a list for each line containing the number of stars then, if there are spaces, the number of spaces and number of stars and repeat for each gap:
letter = [
  *[[20]]*3,
  *[[3, 14, 3]]*2, 
  *[[3, 2, 10, 2, 3]]*4, 
  *[[3, 14, 3]]*2, 
  *[[3, 2, 3 + i, 3, 9-i] for i in range(7)],
  *[[20]]*3,
]

Then to generate the output you can join the alternating sequences of stars-spaces-stars together and then join the lines with new line characters:
output = "\n".join(
  "".join((" " if i%2 else "*")*n for i, n in enumerate(r))
  for r in letter
)

Then, if you want to print it:
print(output + "\n")

Which outputs:
********************
********************
********************
***              ***
***              ***
***  **********  ***
***  **********  ***
***  **********  ***
***  **********  ***
***              ***
***              ***
***  ***   *********
***  ****   ********
***  *****   *******
***  ******   ******
***  *******   *****
***  ********   ****
***  *********   ***
********************
********************
********************

If you want spaces between each character then:
output = "\n".join(
  "".join(("  " if i%2 else "* ")*n for i, n in enumerate(r))
  for r in letter
)
    
print(output + "\n")

Which outputs:
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * *                             * * * 
* * *                             * * * 
* * *     * * * * * * * * * *     * * * 
* * *     * * * * * * * * * *     * * * 
* * *     * * * * * * * * * *     * * * 
* * *     * * * * * * * * * *     * * * 
* * *                             * * * 
* * *                             * * * 
* * *     * * *       * * * * * * * * * 
* * *     * * * *       * * * * * * * * 
* * *     * * * * *       * * * * * * * 
* * *     * * * * * *       * * * * * * 
* * *     * * * * * * *       * * * * * 
* * *     * * * * * * * *       * * * * 
* * *     * * * * * * * * *       * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 


If you want to use loops rather than str.join() then:
output = ""
for r in letter:
    for i, n in enumerate(r):
        output += (" " if i%2 else "*")*n
    output += "\n"

print(output)

